# ==20556== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am almost done writing a bunch of functions for a linked list class I created but for some reason I have one memory leak that stems from the append->insert_back->insert function. Attached is the code for each:

append:

```
void LinkedList<T>::append(const LinkedList<T> &l2)
{
    if (l2.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    //Set current position to l2 head
    LLNode<T> *curr = l2.m_head;
    //For as long as curr->next is not NULL insert to the back of this list the l2 list values
    for(curr; curr->m_next != NULL; curr = curr->m_next){
        insert_back(curr->m_data);
    }
}
```

insert back:

```
void LinkedList<T>::insert_back(const T &x)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        //If the list is empty then use alternative method to store data in back
        LLNode<T> *tmp = m_head;
        while (tmp->m_next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->m_next;
        }
        insert(x, tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        insert(x, getAtPtr(m_size));
    }
}
```

insert:

```
void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T &x, LLNode<T> *pos)
{
    //Create tmp node to store position, set current position data to be passed in x, sets next position to be tmp
    //variable.
    LLNode<T> *tmp = new LLNode<T>;
    *tmp = *pos;
    pos->m_data = x;
    pos->m_next = tmp;
    m_size++;
}
```

and here is the exact memory link error message from valgrind:

```
void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T &x, LLNode<T> *pos)
{
==21462== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==21462==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21462==    by 0x10C4A0: LinkedList<int>::insert(int const&, LLNode<int>*) (in /home/laner107/CS1575/Homework/Homework 2/Homework2/tester.ex)
==21462==    by 0x10BACB: LinkedList<int>::insert_back(int const&) (in /home/laner107/CS1575/Homework/Homework 2/Homework2/tester.ex)
==21462==    by 0x10C1E4: LinkedList<int>::append(LinkedList<int> const&) (in /home/laner107/CS1575/Homework/Homework 2/Homework2/tester.ex)
==21462==    by 0x10AD81: test05() (in /home/laner107/CS1575/Homework/Homework 2/Homework2/tester.ex)
==21462==    by 0x10B46E: main (in /home/laner107/CS1575/Homework/Homework 2/Homework2/tester.ex)
```

where is this memory link occurring at? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the significance of the number in the title?

Comment: You forgot to paste the valrgind message. You pasted the previous code snippet instead.

Comment: `for(curr; ...` - what exactly do you think this is doing? And it's a memory *leak,* not link.

Comment: Isn't this `LLNode<T> *tmp = new LLNode<T>; *tmp = *pos;` the smoking gun?

Comment: Sorry i edited to show the memory link message my copy and paste didnt work before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating an `LLNode<T>` and assigning it to `tmp`. Then tmp is assigned to `pos`. What happened to newly allocated `LLNode<T>`? It is leaked.

Comment: Okay so I change it to be LLNode<T> *tmp = pos; 
and then for some reason when i run it their is an infinite loop inserting something into the list?

Comment: When you insert a new node, a new node has to be allocated *somewhere*. You just need to then attach the node, not leak it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Okay i somewhat understand, im going to try to find an example to look at to understand it more thank you.